# SPF2013 Change Calendar Colors with Jquery

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

First time poster, though I've gotten alot of excellent info off this site in the past.  I have a calendar I'm working on that's giving me fits.  I have set up several event categories and associated views to each category with different colors, which I can display via calendar overlays.  I'd like to display more colors than there are available overlays through jquery.

For each acal-color# div class, sharepoint is adding a title attribute as a string in the following format: [category][range][project][assigned to].  I need to change the color of the event based on "category" and "project" values.  I put together a jfiddle with what I thought would be the solution, but I can't seem to get it to work via a script snippet in Sharepoint.  Jfiddle is here:

[jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2wnkakks/)

If there's any additional info I can provide please let me know.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Got it working using the following:

```
function chCol() {
  setInterval(changeColor, 0);
}
function changeColor() {
  $('div.ms-acal-color3[title*="Index"]').css("background-color", "rgba(0, 140, 255, 0.6)");
  $('div.ms-acal-color4[title*="Index"]').css("background-color", "rgba(0, 100, 255, 0.6)");
  $('div.ms-acal-color5[title*="Index"]').css("background-color", "rgba(0, 200, 255, 0.6)");
    }
  }
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(chCol, "sp.ui.applicationpages.calendar.js");
```

Would definitely be interested in knowing if there's a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS instead of JS:

```
.ms-acal-color# {
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #xxxxxx
}
.ms-acal-selcolor# {
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #xxxxxx
}
.ms-acal-apanel-color# {
 BORDER-COLOR: #xxxxxx;
 BACKGROUND-COLOR: #xxxxxx;
}
```

More detail at http://davidlozzi.com/color-code-sharepoint-calendar/